# Is there a way to rollback an Entity Framework session if one save fails?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Assume I have a student teacher view model and you can save the teacher and then a List of students for the that teacher.

```
    public class StudentTeacherVM()
    {
        public Teacher teacher{ get; set; }
        public List<Student> students { get; set; }
    }
```

The user fills in a teacher and supplies a list of students. I then save all that to the database. I save the teacher, return the new teacherid, then loop through the students, tack on the new teacherid, then save the students.  (follow code just for demonstration, my actual code is much different).

```
    public ActionResult SaveStudent(StudentTeacherVM model)
    {
        Repository repo = new Repository();

        repo.SaveTeacher(model);

        foreach(var s in model.students)
        {
            //add the new teacherid then save the student
            repo.SaveStudent(model);
        }
    }
```

Each of those repo calls opens and closes a db connection because I am using a

```
using(var db = new MyEntity)
{
    db.Teacher.Add(newTeacher);
}
```

What I am trying to do is, if one of the students fail to save, I current spit out the whole list of students, but I also need go back and delete the new teacher that was just entered.

It looks like I can do a "If students fail to save, delete teacher where teacherid = newTeacherId" and it seems to work.

I am wondering if there is some kind of built in 'rollback' feature I can use here, and If there is, am I "disqualified" from using it because I am opening and closing the database connection?

Comment: With EF you should always try to save al work in one `SaveChanges` call, which manages its own transaction. As often with repository-based code, we're looking at a black box that doesn't tell if this is possible at all. I think you shouldn't call SaveChanges in repositories, so you can set references (student.Teacher) instead of FK values. There should be an encompassing UoW that saves all changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your repository class is going to need to expose a transaction scope.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843